# TiffetchNormalTag exception

Tags: c++, linux, imagemagick, libtiff, rhel8

We're using below version on our RHEL 8 VM:

```
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher
Delegates (built-in): jpeg lzma tiff zlib
Compiler: gcc (8.5)
Tiff version: 4.5.1
```

But facing the below in traces:

Magick++ exception: Magick: ASCII value for tag "DocumentName" contains null byte in value; value incorrectly truncated during reading due to implementation limitations. `TIFFFetchNormalTag' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/951

Can you please suggest what could be the issue, or any other resolution for this.
As on solaris no such exception is found , so according to our understanding the image is not corrupted.

Comment: What is the IM version on RHEL and Solaris? RHEL software is frequently out of date (Copyright date of your IM is 1999, which is already quite suspicious).

Comment: Hello,

Please find the IM Versions 

```RHEL 8 :
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-53 Q16 x86_64 20646 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: Cipher 
Delegates (built-in): jpeg lzma tiff zlib
Compiler: gcc (8.5)
```

```Solaris :
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.8-6 Q16 sparc 2017-08-09 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: Cipher DPC Modules
Delegates (built-in): bzlib dps fontconfig freetype jng jpeg ltdl png ps tiff x xml zlib```

Comment: Sounds like that tiff tag is not understood by Imagemagick.

Comment: So is this the issue in the tiff library or the image itself ?